# how to get the middle value in real-time/c++

Tags: c++

If I get some values from the keyboard, how can I find the middle value between them in real time?

this is what I have done but without any result :(

```
float *p=new float;  //p points to the first element
float *my;
std::cin >> my;
vector<float*>V;
V.push_back(my);
std::vector<float*>::iterator it;
p=my;

 while(my){
   it=V.begin()+1;
 }

int M =(*it-p)/2;

delete[] p;
```

to clarify: The middle in terms of order they were given

Comment: Those pointers look really unnecessary.

Comment: I do not know how to find th emiddle one without those pointers!

Comment: There's a `size` function for vectors. Use that. Your use of pointers is going to cause a lot of problems both in execution and readability.

Comment: `float *my; std::cin >> my;` what are you doing :(

Comment: You're also `delete`ing `p` when you never `new` it, which is asking for badness

Comment: @chris: even in real-time?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "real time"?

Comment: @benjymous: float *p=new float;

Comment: @user2758510 yes, even in real time, which we mostly refer to as runtime :)

Comment: What does "middle value" mean? The middle in terms of order they were given, or the median, or the mean?

Comment: middle in terms of order they were given

Comment: @user2758510 when you get comments asking for clarification, you should generally update your question to make it easier to see the *whole* question and give an answer.

Comment: ... and not as an onslaught of wordy "UPDATE" sections, either.

Comment: @benjamin: here is somewhere to ask and learn!!good to know ...

Comment: Just to show you why everyone is freaking out, here is what you're doing: 1) Making a raw pointer to a new object (bad idea in general). 2) Inputting a pointer. 3) Having a vector of pointers instead of objects. 4) Reassigning the pointer in 1), causing a memory leak. 5) Going into an infinite loop because `my` never changes (nor does the vector). 6) Dereferencing `end()` (that's where `it` refers to) and then doing arithmetic with random pointers. 8) Using the wrong `delete` on something that shouldn't be `delete`d at all.

Comment: @user2758510: No offence but it's considered rude to come here and take up our time without doing some learning on your own first. That said, yes, it is good to ask for help. Just as long as you've taken your own time to examine the language first.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It is not fair to react like this..as long as you do not know how much I tried before coming here to get help

Comment: @user2758510: I'm only offering general advice and general statements about how SO should be used. Not accusing you of anything. If I thought you were too lazy then I wouldn't have answered. :) It was your response to Benjamin that sort of implied you thought posting on SO _instead_ of reading a book is okay: it's not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to find the middle value in a container, it's pretty easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<float> v{1,2,3,4,5};

    // Output:     (1,2,3,4,5)
    //          3       ^ 
    std::cout << v.at(v.size()/2) << std::endl;

    // Now a user provides another value, maybe
    v.push_back(6);

    // Output:     (1,2,3,4,5,6)
    //          4         ^
    std::cout << v.at(v.size()/2) << std::endl;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://ideone.com/D04FxO)

Your code has... a lot of problems with pointers.

Comment: I do not know the size of the data! they are producing in real-time..
that makes it complicated!

Comment: @user2758510: You always know the size of the data, whether it's "real-time" or not. It is impossible for you not to know the size of the data, because you're the one who accepted and handled it. The vector always knows how many elements it contains, even as this number changes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You might want to change the example to "enter numbers from the keyboard until zero" or somesuch, rather than having a hard coded vector, to make it clearer to the OP that the size of a vector isn't defined at compile time.

Comment: @benjymous: I don't want to add too much in the program. The OP can read the documentation and the third segment of my example to find out that vectors grow.

Comment: @lightness:I was trying to make a pointer to point to the first element and also I was trying to make another pointer to point to each element wich is producing and then I wanted to check with the while loop to see if still values are producing or not.
if yes, then: (*it-p)/2;
what is the problem in my way?

Comment: @user2758510: I don't even know where to begin. You simply can't check some random uninitialised pointer to see whether a vector has "still values are producing or not". Vectors already have `begin` and `end` iterators, and `size` members. Storing the _elements_ as pointers has gained you nothing but a slew of memory management mess-ups and illegible code. You could have obtained pointers to non-pointer elements and performed pointer arithmetic on those but, as I've demonstrated, even that is entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

@Lightness explained it perfectly. here's another demo (-1 prints the current middle value, -2 exits)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<float> values;
    float value;

    while(std::cin >> value) {
        if(value == -1 && values.size() > 0)
            std::cout << "mid = " << values.at(values.size() / 2) << std::endl;
        else if (value == -2)
            break;
        else
            values.push_back(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one question: why the use of `at`?  `at` is a very special function, which really shouldn't be used unless there is a `try/catch` block somewhere above it to proceed with alternate processing in case of bounds error (which can't occur here anyway).

Comment: i like it because i think it's pretty

Comment: But it's misleading.  It says that you expect (but not too often) out of bounds references, and that they should _not_ be treated as an error, but simply as an exceptional occurance.

Comment: i'm actually used to using them in the way you've mentioned, so it's become a bit of a habit. there was no intentional reason for it.